# What exactly does the phantomjs option "--web-security=false" turn off?

Tags: security, phantomjs

It would make my life a lot easier if I could use cross domain AJAX-Requests. Now I've stumbled upon the `--web-security` option. The documentation states that when turned off cross-domain XHR is possible.

```
--web-security=[true|false] enables web security and forbids cross-domain XHR
                            (default is true). Also accepted: [yes|no].
```

Although this is exactly what I was searching for, I am worried that there might be further security meassures turned off when set to false.

**tl;dr:**

Is this option only turning cross-domain XHR on/off or is it affecting more? And if so: what exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PhantomJS just passes the option on to webkit, and having just poked around the source the only place it is used is here:

https://github.com/adobe/webkit/blob/044126629b2e175119722f58a0098220e0aa0b33/Source/WebCore/dom/Document.cpp#L4557

So, it (`--web-security=no`) is only used for granting access to all origins, and thus only for allowing cross-domain XHR.

Comment: oh okay... so I dont want to turn this option off when my programm is handling very sensitve data... tyvm :)

Comment: @Senad My previous answer was wrong, see updated answer.

Comment: Isn't the origin used for a lot more than just cross-domain *requests*?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Just made my language more precise.